# Google Maps Cursor Misplaced

Tags: dictionary, cursor, offset

When drawing a polygon on a Google Map the little + cursor is offset from the end of the drawn segment and becomes the end of the line if clicked. The little + cursor is always the same distance from the drawn end of the line. What could cause such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had inserted a section above the map canvas and the cursor pointer was off by the exact height of that section.  I moved the section to below the map canvas and the problem disappeared.  There is probably a way for this to have worked with the section on top, but I have no yet figured that out.